# Prevent Sql injection when compose a dynamic Sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had to dynamically create Sql statements for the parameters of a stored procedure due to the legacy database access layer.

```
var p1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(p1).Replace("'", "''").Replace("\n", " ");
var p2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(p2).Replace("'", "''").Replace("\n", " ");
.....
var sql = string.Format("exec storedprocedure @p1='{0}', @p2='{1}', @p3='{2}', ....", 
    p1, p2, p3, ...);
```

Right now I replace `'` to `''` and `\n'` to an empty space after converting the strings to ascii string. What else I need to do? I cannot use `SqlParamter` and had to concat the string due to some facts.

Comment: What about `\'`, ", `\"`, unicode that when decoded in the right way turns into one of the above ( http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11391/how-did-anonymous-use-utf-16-ascii-to-fool-php-escaping ), etc?

Comment: why can't you use SqlParameter?

Comment: @Patashu I've updated the question and force the string to Ascii

Comment: @NickW I'm not sure if forcing it to ASCII fixes it, but I've honestly never tried something like that

Answer (score 1):

Dont.

Use [typed parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx) on all of your queries that have dynamic inputs. All of the flavors of ADO have typed parameters, as well as ADO.NET providers for every database under the sun. If you try to roll your own SQL injection prevention, you're gonna have a bad time.